# Latex acronym package "acronym.sty not found"

Tags: latex

I'm encountering an error when trying to use the `acronym` package. All of my required packages are inside a `myPreamble.sty` file, which I load into my main `tex` file with `\usepackage{myPreamble}`.
I added `\usepackage{acronym}` into said file, but when running `pdflatex main.tex` I'm getting the message
`! LaTeX Error: File 'acronym.sty' not found.`
 I read that `acronym` requires `suffix`, so I added it to `myPreamble` as well, but that resulted in
 `! LaTeX Error: File 'suffix.sty' not found.`
How can I generate these files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error means that you don't have the package installed in your system. You can download the package from [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/acronym) and install it in your system https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows#2066.

On Arch Linux the package comes in the package group `texlive-most`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code on the console. Simply replace the `myfile.sty` with the one missing.

```
tinytex::parse_install(
  text = "! LaTeX Error: File `myfile.sty' not found."
)
```